# Solve for $x$ in $x = \Phi(\Phi^{-1}(2p - x) - s)$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

How can the following equation in $x$, $p$, and $s$ be expressed as $x$ in terms of $p$ and $s$? In other words, how can the second reference to $x$ be eliminated from within the nested $\Phi$ and $\Phi^{-1}$ functions?

$$\begin{gather}
x = \Phi(\Phi^{-1}(2p - x) - s) \\
0 < x < 1 \\
0 < p < 1 \\
s > 0 
\end{gather}$$

$\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution, and $\Phi^{-1}$ is the inverse of the CDF of the standard normal, the probit function.

Comment: Suggestions for how to better frame this question are welcome.

Comment: I tried asking Wolfram Cloud. WC seemed to understand the problem but was not able to find an answer.

Comment: I doubt you can eliminate $x$.

Comment: Newton-Raphson is perfect for such problems.

Comment: Newton-Raphson works well indeed. @KurtG.: please write a short answer to that effect and I will accept as solution.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. Formal MSE answers should be more than just short comments or hints. Give credit to FALAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments suggesting that $x$ is calculated numerically. I also believe that $x$ can be determined graphically. The important question here is whether $x$ exist and is unique. The existence and uniqueness of $x$ can be easily proved by rewriting your equation as $\Phi^{-1}(x) + s = \Phi^{-1}(2p - x)$ and noting that the LHS is an increasing function of $x$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$, while the RHS is a decreasing function of $x$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$ for given values of $p$ and $s$, i.e., there exist a single intersection point between the two curves representing each side depending on the values of $p$ and $s$. Finally, you need to recheck the domains of $p$ and $s$.
[image]